# In WebGPU what's the difference between wgpuBufferDestroy and wgpuBufferRelease?

Tags: webgpu

What's the difference between wgpuBufferDestroy() and wgpuBufferRelease()? Which one am I supposed to call? It's so hard finding information about anything on WebGPU.